# Как защитить update файл от подмены

Tags: linux, безопасность

Как защитить файл от подмены?

Я хотел бы использовать скрипт автоматически устанавливающий update файлы на клиентских машинах. Update файлы я планирую генерировать и рассылать по клиентским машинам автоматически, используя для этого централизованый сервер. И для того чтоб обезопасить себя я хотел бы использовать некое средство, которое могло бы однозначно подтвердить что данное обновление было прислано конкретно с этого сервера.
Каким способом я мог бы решить данную задачу?

Comment: Шифрование по сертификату. Полученный апдейт расшифровывается публичным ключом и устанавливается.

Comment: @Akina, можно ли какую-либо ссылку где я мог бы прочесть об этом подробнее?

Comment: @МаксимПазюк. какой протакол доставки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так как публичный ключ все равно будет доступен, то большой необходимости шифровать нет. Можно просто делать цифровую подпись. Если очень-очень кратко, неким алгоритмом считаем хеш от сообщения (текста файла) и дописываем его в конец/отдельный файл. На принимающей стороне делаем аналогичную парную процедуру и сверяем. Если не совпадает - файл поменяли. Но для подписывания и проверки используются различные ключи. Поэтому ключ подписывания (приватный ключ) известен только ограниченному кол-ву людей. А публичный ключ (для проверки) доступен всем желающим.

На [wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) развернуто написано.

В линуксе есть [GPG](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuPG), [статья-туториал](https://eax.me/gpg/). Скорее всего он "из коробки" умеет все нужное делать.

Answer (score 1):

например:

1. вы можете забирать сами файлы по протоколу https с вашего сервера
2. если канал доставки файлов иной, с вашего сервера по протоколу https вы можете забирать лишь хэш-суммы файлов и сверять их с хэш-суммами полученных
3. как упомянуто в ответе @KoVadim, можно использовать ассиметричное шифрование — с помощью программ gpg или openssl